# How to pass button title to next view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, segue, viewcontroller

I have several buttons defined in a loop in viewDidLoad. They are inside a content view, which is in a scroll view.

```
    for var i:Int = 0; i < colleges.count; i++ {

        let collegeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        collegeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, 30)
        collegeButton.center = CGPoint(x: self.contentView.center.x, y: 30 * CGFloat(i) + 30)
        collegeButton.setTitle(sortedColleges[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        collegeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        collegeButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN", size: 15)
        collegeButton.addTarget(self, action: "collegeSelected:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.contentView.addSubview(collegeButton)
    }
```

As you can see, the title of each button is set based on a previously defined array of strings. Whenever a button is selected, a segue is called to move to a table view, which is embedded in a navigation controller.

I need to set the navigation controller title to be the same as the specific button title.

Here are some things I have tried:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destViewController:videosTableView = segue.destinationViewController as videosTableView
    //destViewController.title = collegeButton.titleLabel?.text

    //var buttonTitle = sender.titleLabel?.text
    //destViewController.title = buttonTitle
}
```

The commented lines were failed attempts.

I also tried working in the action function called when the button is pressed:

```
func collegeSelected(sender: UIButton!) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToTableView", sender: self)

    //Set navigation title of next screen to title of button
    var buttonTitle = sender.titleLabel?.text
    println(buttonTitle)

}
```

Using the sender to get the button title works, but I don't know how to pass it to the next view controller.

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button function, pass the button along as the sender of the segue:

```
func collegeSelected(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToTableView", sender: sender)
}
```

Then in `prepareForSegue`, get the button title from the sender (i.e. the button):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as videosTableView

    if let buttonTitle = (sender as? UIButton)?.titleLabel?.text {
        destViewController.title = buttonTitle
    }
}
```